# Line could not be drawn with Hightcharts for the data of many points

Tags: highcharts

I tried to plot a graph with line style for the data more than 300 points. I could not obtain the expected graph but only with markers. However, when I zoom the graph, the line can be seen. I have done a lot work to show the line but I failed. Lastly when I reduced the number of the data points, I could see the line.  I have experienced with flot but I have not encountered this kind of problems. Is is a bug in the highcharts? How can I overcome this difficulty? I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Can you show some demo or a relevant code ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not enough width of container, and markers "overlap" line. So try to disable markers http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.marker.enabled and check if line appears.

ps. sourcecode will be helpful (could you reproduce it in jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answering. I also tried to enable the markers not to show but the line still did not appear. I also tried to use a very large container to draw but did the same results. Fortunately, when I checked my data again with JSON.stringify, I found the last plot data is [NaN, NaN]. When I remove this data and plot again, I got the line plot. The reason that I created the data from a text file and forgot to trim the text. When I added /removed [NaN, NaN] from the data array, the line could be shown or disappeared. The phenomena can be reproduced. Thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your attention for this question. I have solved the problem by myself.
When I checked my data again with JSON.stringify, I found the last plot data is [NaN, NaN]. When I remove this data and plot again, I got the line plot. The reason that I created the data from a text file and forgot to trim the text. When I added /removed [NaN, NaN] from the data array, the line could be shown or disappeared. The phenomena can be reproduced.

Here is the sample code. The data1 can not be shown in line but data2 can.
    var chart;

```
var data1 = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [3, 5],
  [10, 9]
 ];


data1.push([NaN, NaN]); // if the last data is [NaN, NaN], the line will not be shown.

var data2 = [
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [10, 1]

];



$(function () {
    // define the options
    var options = {

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                    lineWidth: 2,

                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'test 1',
            data: data1
        }, {
            name: 'test 2',
            data: data2
        }]
    };

 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


});
```